# Bootstrap Navbar causing spacing on the right hand side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am aware that there are other questions addressing this issue. However, I have tried them and nothing appears to work for my particular issue. I have also noticed that most are quite old and bootstrap has changed somewhat in that time. So I am asking again. Apologies.

I have a theme that I found on codepen that I am modifying to gain a better understanding of bootstrap as per some tips from freecodecamp. I am tearing my hair out over this last simple thing.

Tha navbar is creating unnecessary white space throughout the entire site on the right margin.

It is present here: http://codepen.io/Er-c/pen/YGzkmG/

Relevant code (I think)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right links">
        <li class="hidden">
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

What on earth can I do to eliminate the white over on the right:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4thMT.png)

I am totally stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trouble actually isn't coming from the nav: it's right padding on the cityscape. `.col-` classes get a `padding-right`, so there's padding on the right of your `main #about .row.pt-30 div`.

There are various ways to get around this. Searching SO will give you a lot of people recommending you add a "no right padding" class, like

```
.dont-pad-me {padding-right: 0}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 dont-pad-me">
```

but in this case I think you just want to replace

```
<div class="row pt-30">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <img class="peeping-tom" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/awsxg2.png" alt="#">
  </div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="container-fluid pt-30">
    <img class="peeping-tom" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/awsxg2.png" alt="#">
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Side note: Bootstrap's `.col-` widths are "this size and up" - so to get `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"` you only have to use `class="col-xs-12"`. If you *only* have `.col-xs-12` there's no need to use a grid, but this can be useful if you wanted to do something like `class="col-xs-3 col-lg-4"`

Comment: Btw this is my technique for fixing things this: I inspect the page (or in this case I inspected your pen), add `display:none` to elements, and see if the problem horizontal scroll goes away. If it does, remove the `display:none` and start adding it that element's children. If you start with `body`, you can quickly narrow it down to the problem

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, I was gonna ask but didn't wanna pester you. Thank you for teaching this man to fish.

Comment: For sure! And on SO you'll always be safe asking for clarification and explanation. Everyone here — well… almost everyone ;) — is here to help others learn. Worst that can happen is you don't hear back

Answer (score 0):

If You want to gain better understanding in navbar, try this link and it is very simple and clear. Give it a try http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: yeah thank you, funnily enough, when I paste in that default navbar as a replacement for my current one, the white space on the right still remains.

Comment: answer was apparently to do "overflow-x: hidden", thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add **overflow-x: hidden;** to body and it's solved.

P.s: The issue isn't caused by the navbar (deleted it, issue was still present), but there's way too much code to tell it right now.

Comment: Thank you, it's weird, I am confident I tried it, but now that I think about it, I forgot to format it properly via SASS. ugh. my bad. Thank you so much.